# How to trigger branch commit pipeline after MR pipeline succeed?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to run job "uploading" only if job "checking" was successful, but it appears that my jobs have different rules, so **needs:["checking"]** cannot be applied. First job is triggered only during merge request (Merge Request pipeline) and the second one after I've merged this MR in master branch.

```
stages:
  - check_if_MR_contains_some_text

checking:
  stage: check_if_MR_contains_some_text
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
  script:
    - ...

uploading:
  stage: check_if_MR_contains_some_text
  rules:
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
```

It seems like these jobs are counted as a separate pipelines. Is there a way to achieve desired logic across two independent jobs?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to enforce it in my opinion is to check the `pipelines must succeed` option
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_when_pipeline_succeeds.html#require-a-successful-pipeline-for-merge
+ set master/main branch to be protected - prohibiting pushes directly to it.
this will ensure that anything that is already merged passed the checks

If that is too harsh in your current scenario - I would add `allow_failure: true` to jobs that are allowed to fail.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure

final option - is to run the first check also in branches, and add `optional: true` to the needs dependency.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional.

In addition to all of the above - I would perhaps add this as a pre-commit check :)